# How to fix small unicode text in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, fonts, unicode

I use Bengali texts to name some of my folder/files in windows 7, but the texts appear awfully small which bugs me a lot. Is there any way to fix this? What I want is to have the Bengali texts shown a little bigger, *without affecting any other text sizes*. I have seen that in windows 8 this is no longer a problem, Bengali text in windows 8 is well-displayed. I tried using windows 8 Segoe fonts in my windows 7, but that seemed to have fixed only Arabic texts, and no change to Bengali texts.

[image: bangla texts, default]